# How to enable div to appear over the selected text?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuejs2

I am creating an application using VueJS to generate a tooltip over user selected text. I want to show the tooltip exactly over the user selected text.  I am using [Tippy.js](https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/) to create the tooltip

Here is the code:

```js
const giphy = require('giphy-api')('Here goes the API key');

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      
    }
  },

  mounted() {
    const template = document.querySelector('#template');
    const initialText = template.textContent;
    
    let that = this;

    const tip = tippy('.tip', {
      animation: 'shift-toward',
      arrow: true,
      html: '#template',
      trigger: 'click',
      onShow() {
        
        // `this` inside callbacks refers to the popper element
        const content = this.querySelector('.tippy-content');
        
        if(tip.loading || content.innerHTML !== initialText) 
          return;
        
        tip.loading = true;

        var self = that;
        
        $('#app').mouseup(function() {
          let selection = self.getSelected();

          if (selection != "") {

            giphy.translate(`${selection}`)
            .then(function (response) {
              // Assigning the url from response object to the url
              const url = response.data.images.fixed_width_small.url;
              content.innerHTML = `<img width="100" height="100" src="${url}">`
              tip.loading = false
            })
            .catch(function(error){
              content.innerHTML = 'Loading failed'
              tip.loading = false
            });

          }
        });
      },

      onHidden() {
        const content = this.querySelector('.tippy-content');
        content.innerHTML = initialText;
      }
    })

  },

  methods: {
    // Function to get the selected text
    getSelected() {
      let selectedText = "", selection;
      
      if (window.getSelection) {
        selectedText = "" + window.getSelection();
      } 
      else if ( (selection = document.selection) && selection.type == "Text") {
        selectedText = selection.createRange().text;
      }
      return selectedText;
    }

  }
```

```css
#app {
  font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 250px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <div class="tip">
      <h1>Fifa World Cup 2018</h1>
      <h4 style="margin-top:40px;">Winner is France</h4>
      <span style="margin-top:10px;">Runner up is Croatia</span>
    </div>

    <div>
      <div id="template" style="display: none">
        Loading tooltip...
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

The div with id="template" is the div that forms the tooltip. So far, I have only managed to make it appear at the center of the div in which the text is present. How can I make sure the tooltip appears exactly above the selected text? Can someone please help me out here?

Comment: Script error, doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

1. register `mouseup` event handler on app
2. in handler call `window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).getBoundingClientRect()` to get the bounding rectangle of the text selection
3. pass the bounding rectangle of the text selection to tippy as a "virtual element", docs: https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/ (crtl+f "virtual element")

vanilla JS example of the first 2 steps:

```js
let p = document.querySelector('p');
let div = document.querySelector('div');

document.documentElement.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
    console.log(p);
    let selection = getSelection();
    console.log(selection);
    if (!selection.isCollapsed && selection.rangeCount > 0) {
        let range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
        console.log(range);
        let rangeRect = range.getBoundingClientRect();
        console.log(rangeRect);
        console.log(div);
        div.style.top = rangeRect.top+'px';
        div.style.left = rangeRect.left+'px';
        div.style.width = rangeRect.width+'px';
        div.style.height = rangeRect.height+'px';
    } else {
        div.style.top = 0;
        div.style.left = 0;
        div.style.width = 0;
        div.style.height = 0;
    }
});
```

```css
body {
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
}

div {
    border: 2px red solid;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    top: -999px;
    left: -999px;
}

p {
    width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<h1> try selecting some of the text below </h1>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
```

Comment: Can you please edit the above code and show me how I can do it? I would really appreciate that. In that way, I can figure out what I need to do